# Cross-Platform In-App Monetization with Cordova

Tags: cordova

I am developing a game using Telerik AppBuilder, and am looking for the best and easiest way to perform in-app monetization functionality like hint purchasing, puzzle bundle unlocking, etc.

Are there any truly cross-platform solutions for Cordova that actually let you write once, run anywhere, in the sense that you're performing a financial traction with Apple's app store or an Android store, depending on the platform you've deployed to?

Answer (score 1):

there are no truly cross-platform solutions for Cordova that I am aware of. Cordova itself would not support/maintain this kind of plugin (due to the nature of the plugin) and so it would be up to a third party. However, drawing from multiple sources can get you a working solution

## Native (recommended)

The best (re: most stable) is to wrap the native in-app billing systems that already exist on the platforms.

iOS has the [in-app purchase program](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html)
Android has [in-app billing as a google service](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html)

Use the natively provided frameworks for billing, and simply wrap

## Plugins

note that these plugins wrap the native functionality present on the given platform

Android
https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling

iOS
https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS

Solutions for crossplatform in app billing have come and gone, and we are likely to see many more. I doubt you will find a canonical rock solid example that will work outside of the box.

## Third Party

Urban Airship **used** to offer something, which apparently is now deprecated: https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/1099036-in-app-purchase-sunset-migration-guide

I don't believe third party payment systems would work for you.

There are many many third party services that offer in-app purchasing, but they are limited to selling actually goods and services by iOS dev license agreement. [Here's an SO topic discussing this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566671/ios-app-does-apple-allow-3rd-party-payments-inside-app) Digital goods MUST be handled by the in-app purchasing system offered by Apple.

Comment: Native is definitely better. Everything is already built out for you.

Comment: agreed @dperconti, moved the native recommendation to the top and adjusted formatting. It should be noted that the plugin solution should wrap the natively provided in-app purchasing framework, hence the lack of cross-platform plugins